# security implications of javascript entity decode then encode

Tags: javascript, dojo, xss, html-entities

We have a web app that is under going a massive code regeneration and as a result large components are getting a security overhaul. As such we are having issues with double escaping of html entities.

for example:

[image]
The issue arises from the i18n'd string already being html encoded when passed to our toast widget - and the new toast widget is again html encoding the characters.

The question is, are there any security implications of doing this (in pseudo code)

```
Entities.encode(Entities.decode(string));
```

to get around the double encoding issues whilst we migrate the massive codebase? Are there any issues associated with non-encoded strings passing through decode first?

Comment: Not certain how there could be "security implications" if you are composing the code?

Comment: Entity encoding is so HTML is rendered correctly. It has nothing to do with Security.

Comment: @guest271314 because the messages can contain user content

Comment: @PHPglue Not true. If the entities are not encoded it can allow XSS vectors since it would not escape any user submitted html.

Comment: That effects HTML rendering. If it's `.innerHTML` or actual HTML then you will want to use HTML Entities. If you assign JavaScript properties besides `.innerHTML`, like `Element.value = 'Yes & Works'` or `Element.title = '5 < 4'`, then you do not use HTML Entities.

Comment: @buggedcom Still not sure how encoding and decoding data is related to security?

Answer (score 1):

You should also design your pages to encode at the point at which the code is being written out to the page, this ensures you're encoding for the correct context, and avoids double encoding.  But there are times when it's not feasible to go through all the code and fix that.

From a security perspective you will end up with "safe" HTML (an attacker will be unable to break out into code context).  As always, you need to be sure you are using the correct encoding for the correct context and quoting your entities.

You are likely to end up with functional regressions, however.  If the data originally contained valid encoded characters (&lt) those will now show up as their encoded equivalents (<).

Of course, you are likely doing this to avoid regressions of double encoding, so this may be a trade off you're willing to make.  You can also try and limit the decode a limited set of common characters, which should still be safe as long as you are using the full encode.